# Class member function as callback to imported dll

Tags: c++, callback, dllimport, pointer-to-member

I have a dll that has exported the following functions. One of these functions is a callback function definition and the other one is a function to set callback.

```
typedef void __stdcall RawStreamingCallback (RawData const *);

void __stdcall OpenRawStreaming (int TunerId, RawStreamingCallback *pCallback);
```

I want to set a class member function as callback function. This is my own class definition:

```
public class XX {
public:
    XX() {}


    void CALLBACK RawStreamingCallbackkk(RawData const *data) {}

    bool startStreamingCallback(int tunerId) {
        RawStreamingCallback* p = (RawStreamingCallback *)(this->RawStreamingCallbackkk);

        OpenRawStreaming(tunerId, p);
    }
};
```

When I build the code, it gives me the following error:

> type cast': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'RawStreamingCallback (__cdecl *)'

If I declare my callback function as static, it is running. But I need to use member function of X class. Because there will be list of XX class objects and I should know which callback for which object.

Is it possible to use class member function as a callback function for imported dlls?

Comment: Normally, callbacks take a user data pointer where you can smuggle your object pointer through. Since this API does not allow that, you need to generate a custom callback tied to your object. See my answer using libffi in [C++ "Dynamic" function pointers for C callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719322/c-dynamic-function-pointers-for-c-callback-functions)

Comment: That doesn't look like a very good interface. I would expect either a "user data" to associate with the callback when you register it, or the tuner ID to passed to the callback (in case there can only be one callback per ID, which seems reasonable). It would make sense if there can only be one stream open at a time, though.

Comment: By the way: this problem has nothing to do with DLLs.

Comment: Yes, if the callback function had tunerId as member, I could handle the stuation. Unfortinetly it doesn't have. So I wonder is it possible that using class member function as callback.

Comment: @DoganX It's not possible. You need to "pass through" a free function or a static member. There might be some way to solve your problem with this library, but it's impossible to tell from the few details you provided. What does `RawData` contain?

Comment: @molbdnilo this is the structure of it;

typedef struct {
 unsigned short Block[4];
} RDSRawData;

Comment: you want have additional parameter in callback function (*this* pointer) but caller not provide this parameter. the only solution here have 2 in 1 - pass special stub function pointer, which containing pointer to your class and call your member function with this additional. solution will be os specific, platform specific, and require some code in asm

Comment: Then I'm afraid that you can't accomplish what you want except by using something like the libffi suggestion. Are you sure that the library *can* open more than one stream at a time?