# Template generating a hundred C callback functions, without slow compilation

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I need to pass order of a hundred callback functions to a C library. All my callbacks will be very similar, except that they need to know which "key" it was registered for. The C API doesn't allow an context to be passed back.

In other words this is the API:

```
void register_for_event(int event_type, void(*callback)());
```

I came up with this template metaprogramming:

```
template<int event_type>
void event_handler() {
  std::cout << "Event: " << event_type << std::endl;
}

template <int n = 100>
void register_event_handlers() {
  register_for_event(n, event_handler<n>);
  register_event_handlers<n-1>();
}
template<> void register_event_handlers<0>(){}
```

But is there a way to write this:

- easier to read
- faster to compile (the above adds several seconds to building the file, with gcc)

Any version of C++, up to C++20, would work for me.

I'm trying to avoid macros, though it's not obvious to me how macros would even help here.

I could use code generation from shell script. I may end up doing this if I can't find a better C++-native way. But I'm also interested in what other native C++ ways are possible.

Comment: I don't see anything in your example code that needed to be discerned at compile time.  So a loop and a function that accepted an integer parameter would have worked here.  Maybe your example is too simple?

Comment: @Wyck the integer parameter is also a template argument for `event_handler`.

Comment: Yup. But the event handler is under my control, so if there's another solution that for example could call a common function `event_handler_for_all_events(int event_type)` that would be great.

Comment: If you are willing to accept a dependency on libffi you can use its trampolining functionality to generate those 100 callbacks. I wrote an answer for that some time ago.

Comment: Dug it up for you: [C++ “Dynamic” function pointers for C callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722596/1548468)

Comment: @Botje Awesome, Thanks.

Comment: @Botje, yes, of course, I see that. But the implementation does not do anything special with it.  I realize it's a placeholder implementation.  I was just worried that it was a little too simplistic of an example.  If it just had `Foo<n>` as the type instead of just `n` and the implementation didn't just pass n to a function like cout.  Anyway, like I said, I realize it's just a placeholder.  cout << n is exceedingly simple to warrant metaprogramming and wanted to make sure it's not just `std::bind` that is needed here.

Comment: @Wyck do you have a solution in mind that would work if it's not `cout << n` but one C++ function (under your control)? I'm not quite following what you're saying.

Comment: Before I answer that, are you really using a lame API that asks you for a C-style function pointer but doesn't also take a `void*` argument for the context of that callback?  If so then you are stuck with generating all the code as you have done.  But if it takes a context argument then just provide the bound arguments via the context.  This is why any modern C api uses `void register_for_event(int event_type, void(*callback)(void* context), void* context)`  or in C++, takes a `std::function` as the callback type.  Your `register_for_event` API suffers from that shortcoming. :(

Comment: @Wyck yes I am stuck with this API. If a context is available this would be much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a C++17 answer:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
void register_via_pack(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    ( (register_for_event(I, event_handler<I>)),... );
}

register_via_pack(std::make_index_sequence<100>{});
```

It expands a template parameter pack using a C++17 fold expression. Not sure if it compiles faster in your scenario, but it is a good 4 times faster here under g++ -O3. Even under -Og it produces unrolled code instead of a 100-deep recursion.

You can use [the trick here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375089/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-print-a-variadic-parameter-pack-using-stdostream) to do the same under C++11/C++14.

You can get rid of the extra function by using an immediately-invoked variadic templated lambda function, but it will not be more readable ;)

Comment: I suspect this is as good as it gets. Clang (and I think GCC?) has special compiler support for make_index_sequence, which hugely cuts down compile time versus manual recursive instantiation